Error API_KEY_HTTP_REFERRER_BLOCKED at using Youtube Data API v3
I have a problem with API.
I try get metadata from MW Metadata from https://github.com/mattwright324/youtube-metadata and i have a error:
{
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseText": "{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 403,\n    \"message\": \"Requests from referer https://example.com are blocked.\",\n    \"errors\": [\n      {\n        \"message\": \"Requests from referer https://example.com are blocked.\",\n        \"domain\": \"global\",\n        \"reason\": \"forbidden\"\n      }\n    ],\n    \"status\": \"PERMISSION_DENIED\",\n    \"details\": [\n      {\n        \"@type\": \"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo\",\n        \"reason\": \"API_KEY_HTTP_REFERRER_BLOCKED\",\n        \"domain\": \"googleapis.com\",\n        \"metadata\": {\n          \"consumer\": \"projects/0000000000\",\n          \"service\": \"youtube.googleapis.com\"\n        }\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n",
    "responseJSON": {
        "error": {
            "code": 403,
            "message": "Requests from referer hhttps://example.com are blocked.",
            "errors": [
                {
                    "message": "Requests from referer https://example.com are blocked.",
                    "domain": "global",
                    "reason": "forbidden"
                }
            ],
            "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
            "details": [
                {
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                    "reason": "API_KEY_HTTP_REFERRER_BLOCKED",
                    "domain": "googleapis.com",
                    "metadata": {
                        "consumer": "projects/639927084543",
                        "service": "youtube.googleapis.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "status": 403,
    "statusText": "error"
}

I tried to disable the API key restriction but that doesn't do anything either. The help from another thread doesn't work either.

Please edit your question and include your code
